# Why Kidd/Hawkins/Apoo alliance are planning to take down Shanks?

Tags: one-piece

Just in latest episode of One piece (Episode 736). There was one scene which shows that Kidd/Hawkins/Apoo alliance are planning to take down Shanks.

So my question is, Why Shanks? I mean there has to be some sort of reason behind this. Why didn't they choose someone else. What's the main reason behind this?

Note: I follow Anime rather than Manga

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Credits for the image goes to Saji D Ahsan

Comment: There is a speculation where Kid and Shanks are related (perhaps father) so the reason could be about their past. There is no information about this in neither manga nor anime.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why they target him hasn't been revealed yet, so only assumptions can be made so far. Mine is that they don't have any specific reason to do so in-universe, as all Emperors seem to be roughly equal in strength (Or if they aren't, there is nothing yet that can reasonably show us who is stronger and who is weaker) and their target just happened to be the only Emperor who isn't antagonistic towards Luffy.

Answer (score -1):

As we can see Blackbeard who killed WhiteBeard and even get his Devil Fruit , Kaido who is a known Pirate who have a Devil-Fruit Army and Big Mom who have a large army and Island under his name. Considering the power of Kid Alliance it is impossible for them to take down this Emperors unlike Shanks who is a non Devil Fruit user (as of now) would likely be their target.